# Would Adding NordVPN to a Windows Server Block Remote Access at Its IP?

Tags: windows, vpn

I have a Windows Server with a Puppeteer app that scrapes various websites. Some of those sites have blocked the IP address, so I need to use something like a VPN so that I can change the IP address when that happens. I already have a Nord VPN account and would like to use that, but I have only used it on a desktop and am not sure what impact that would have on the ability to access my remote server at its IP address.

Would installing a VPN block external access to the server?

I only want to use the VPN for outgoing connections. I already installed NordVPN but it requires a restart and during the install I got this error https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Windows/1047410022/TAP-driver-error-when-connecting-to-a-VPN.htm and I fear restarting the machine might make it inaccessible via RDC at its IP address because if NordVPN starts running the connection it might act as a buffer between that IP and the rest of the internet.

Comment: A more responsible approach would be to honor the other sites not wanting you scraping them.

Answer (score 0):

If you install vpn to your remote server, your server gets an ip which is for a pool of computers. And there is no port forwarding. When you send RDP request to that vpn ip, it wont know to which should it forward the request. **You will probably loose RDP access.**  Some software use their own server to meet computers for remote access. Hence,  teamviewer like software should not loose their function.

On the other hand, as I recall, win10 introduced a computer-name-access-method for RDP. I did not tested win10's remote access by computer name feature. If its like teamviewer or alpemix, you should not loose access.

Comment: Would my websites be inaccessible at that IP address for the same reason. That is what I fear most. My DNS at my registrar points to the static IP address of the server specifically. Is there a way to use the VPN for outgoing connections only?

Comment: yes it will probably be inaccessible